# Does the ExternalInterface, in Flex 3, have a data size limitation?

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, flash, compression, externalinterface

I am using the ExternalInterface on Flex 3. We are actually using flex to compress a large amount of DOM data, so this is specifically being used with LARGE data.

To further investigate, if there is a limitation, is this universal? (IE. Silverlight)

First, let me state that this is being done with an application that was made by inexperienced software engineers. This is an app that we need to buy time by compressing the data so that we can build a long-term solution. We have no other options, unfortunately.

Background: This is an application that is actually a web-spreadsheet. Our long term solution is to make a Office Business Application.

Comment: I am not aware of any upper limits - just out of curiosity: what made you choose flex for compression, rather than doing it in js itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Flash do not impose any size limits on ExternalInterface communication.

Answer (score 0):

I think it does, or there is some other configuration which governs this. I was testing a file upload using FileReference object and wanted to pass the data sent from server back to hosting page via external interface call. Below is a snippet of my UPLOAD_COMPLETE_DATA event handler

```
    private function onFileUploadCompleteData (e:DataEvent):void
    {
        var file:FileReference = FileReference(e.target);
        Alert.show("onFileUploadCompleteData : " + e.data );

        if(ExternalInterface.available && callBackOnUploadCompleteData.length > 0)
        {
            var data:Object = new Object();
            data.FileName = file.name;
            data.ServerData = e.data;
            //data.ServerData = e.data.substr(0, 50);
            ExternalInterface.call(callBackOnUploadCompleteData, data);
        }
    }
```

This event gets fired but the call to my javascript is never made. If I uncomment the line which trims the returned data to first 50 characters, it start working and calls the javascript correctly.

Either there is a size restriction imposed by flash (10.2) or IE9 (which is what I was using), or there is something else I am missing.

Comment: thank, I need to test this. Is there simple way to encode in flex?