# How to send commands from the c# application to its hosted adobe flash application?

Tags: c#, flash

I have an c# application that hosts(using Shockwave Flash Object that is in AxInterop.ShockwaveFlashObjects.dll) a flash application.
 I can send commands from flash application to my c# application using "fscommand" of flash.
Now I need to send commands (like setting a flash text) from c# application to flash application, can I do that? how?

Comment: It should be possible through [ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6)

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza: Thanks for the reply, is there any c# sample of using ExternalInterface?

Comment: try [this](http://blog.another-d-mention.ro/programming/communicate-betwen-c-and-an-embeded-flash-application/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways to achieve:

1. As George Profenza has pointed out, using [ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) is a simple implementation which enables two-way communication.  It can handle some primitive data back and forth, and is ideal for hosted-Flash communication that involves small amount data in every call. However, there is [size limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862185/does-the-externalinterface-in-flex-3-have-a-data-size-limitation) as to how much data can be sent and received.
2. If size does matter, [XmlSocket](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/XMLSocket.html) would be another option that allows stateful two-way communication.  On C# end, you may use [snippet like this](http://www.koders.com/csharp/fid38B6B346DEFB346620FE375C9F610A9C5D020DA6.aspx?s=file#L109) to create XmlSocket server, and have the host application host the server as well, then have Flash connect to the server on start.  There is no size limit, but you would have to encode every call into XML, so it is a little bit of overhead to serialize and de-serialize data on both end.  I have used this technology in some standalone .NET base Winform applications successfully for years.
3. A 3rd option would be utilizing FlashRemoting.  It is similar to the strategy used in the above option, but the "server" would be a Flash Remoting server which is capable of communicating with Flash using AMF.  The major advantage of this approach is that you don't have to write any serialize/deserializer as the server and Flash would take care of that for you, and there is no size limit either, it is ideal for scenarios where you have a variety of calls with complex data structure.  However, there is an up-front cost of integrating the server.  There are [open-source solution](http://www.fluorinefx.com/) and [closed-source solutions](http://www.themidnightcoders.com/products/weborb-for-net/overview.html).

The 3rd option may not be explored as most people would use it for web applications.  I personally favor the 3rd option though I have no first-hand experience integrating it as a windows form application.  I favor it as it has potential to easily turn the application into a web-based application, and it also supports complex data structure without the expense of data serialization.

Comment: Well explained and documented +1